# How to check user activeness (from database) before login in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-authentication

In my application, there is a 'status' column in the 'users' table. Which indicates the user activeness. Now I want to check the activeness of the user before login to the system and give a message if he is deactivated. How to do this? There are several answers here, but I cannot make this work with the help of those answers.

This is my LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');


    }




}
```

Comment: you sould override methods that you need from this address: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` ---- and in `login` method when it's getting start you can do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `authenticated()` method.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // Check status
        if ($user->status == 'inactive') {
            $this->logout($request);

            // Send message
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [__('Your status is inactive')],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware class to check the status column. For example:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckStatusMiddleware {

    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->firstOrFail();

        if (!$user->active)
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then register the class and apply it to the necessary route(s).

See [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) for more information.